# How to change working directory in Termux

Tags: android, termux

Im running Termux on an Android 10 smartphone. Termux is fully upgraded and updated. But I can't access device storage(/storage/emulated/0).
I tried 'cd' command, and it works. But whenever I try to access a file or folder it says 'no access'. Plz help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For accessing to shared storage (/sdcard or /storage/emulated/0), Termux needs a storage access permission. It is not granted by default and is not requested on application startup because it is not necessary for normal applications.

In order to have access you should run

> termux-setup-storage

command. Then you can have access to various paths like :

- ~/storage/shared : this is the root of shared storage
- ~/storage/downloads : this is the common folder for downloads
- ~/storage/dcim : this is normal directory for pictures and vidoes captured by camera

Answer (score 2):

1. Setup your phone internal storage in termux, using this command:

   ```
   termux-setup-storage
   ```
2. Change your directory using this command:

   ```
   cd /sdcard
   ```

Now you can easily access your internal storage.